# Missing path to your environment variable Mujoco210

Tags: python, conda, openai-gym, mujoco

I am getting this error, as I am using mujoco210 version which is the free version released by DeepMind recently.

```
Missing path to your environment variable. 
Current values LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sagar/.mujoco/mujoco210/bin
Please add following line to .bashrc:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/sagar/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around the error by first uninstalling the previous version of mujoco-py and installing the free-mujoco-py version.

```
$ conda uninstall mujoco-py
$ pip install free-mujoco-py
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Mujoco version for your machine and extract its contents to ~/.mujoco directory (don't forget the dot).
Now add this environment variable,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/sagar/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin
```